# How to update the next row of the current row when a condition is met

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable, dplyr

I have a data table as below:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

dput(data)
structure(list(Id = c(1, 1, 1, 1), start = structure(c(1509525095, 
1509529535, 1509532655, 1509543455), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "NA"), end = structure(c(1509525450, 1509529535, 1509535650, 
1509549450), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "NA"), spot = structure(c(1509524490, 
1509529235, 1509529715, 1509542250), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "NA"), type = structure(c(1L, 1L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3"), class = "factor"), consumption = structure(c(10.0833333333333, 
5, 49, 20.0833333333333), units = "mins", class = "difftime")), .Names = c("Id", 
"start", "end", "spot", "type", "consumption"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

From this I want to add a new column **spot_new** to the row **after** the row 
  where  the conditon **start=end** end is met.

I tried

```
  data[start=end, data:=c(NA, spot[-.N]), by=Id]
```

But this doesn't do what I wanted.Any help is appreciated.

**Desired Output**

[image: Desired Output]

Comment: In this case, the 2nd row is where they are the same.  what if there are multiple rows that have same value for start and end.  It is not clear what the expected output would be

Comment: Perhaps you need `i1 <- data[,  .I[seq(which(start == end)+1, .N, by = 1)], Id]$V1; data[i1, spot_new := spot]`

Comment: Yeah there are multiple rows with start=end

Comment: But `i1 <- data[, .I[seq(which(start == end)+1, .N, by = 1)], Id]$V1; data[i1, spot_new := spot]` return me a vector 0f 3 and 4\

Comment: It is better you update the post with the expected output..  For me, it is not clear about how you wanted to do do this for multiple row conditions etc.

Comment: @akrun I added the desired output.This is a sample table and I have many Id s as well.So basically I need to do a group by Id as well

Comment: Please fix your example. It throws errors

Comment: What error does it throws?

Comment: You just need to change the `seq` part to `.I[which(start == end)+1]`

Comment: The below `i1 <- data[, .I[(which(start == end)+1, .N, by = 1)], Id]$V1; data[i1, spot_new := spot]` produces a single column with 2 rows (3,4)

Comment: `Error: unexpected symbol in "data=data.table(data)data"` and `Error in `:=`(consumption, (start - spot)) : 
  Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").`

Comment: Can you check now?

Comment: same errors again. It's simpler to post `dput(data)`

Comment: Now should be fine

Comment: Nope. Same errors. Just use `dput`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162504/discussion-between-ricky-and-sotos).

Comment: @akrun Could you help me with the full line instead of a pert of it.Thanks

Comment: @Ricky I posted a solution with the full line of code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can offer a `dplyr` solution which works with a `rowwise`, `if else` statement in order to fill the column with the `spot`. We then use `lag` to move it a position, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 group_by(Id) %>% 
 rowwise() %>% 
 mutate(spot_new = if(start == end){spot}else(NA)) %>% 
 ungroup() %>% 
 mutate(spot_new = lag(spot_new))
```

which gives

> ```
> # A tibble: 4 x 7
>      Id               start                 end                spot   type   consumption            spot_new
>   <dbl>              <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm> <fctr>        <time>              <dttm>
> 1     1 2017-11-01 08:31:35 2017-11-01 08:37:30 2017-11-01 08:21:30      1 10.08333 mins                  NA
> 2     1 2017-11-01 09:45:35 2017-11-01 09:45:35 2017-11-01 09:40:35      1  5.00000 mins                  NA
> 3     1 2017-11-01 10:37:35 2017-11-01 11:27:30 2017-11-01 09:48:35      3 49.00000 mins 2017-11-01 09:40:35
> 4     1 2017-11-01 13:37:35 2017-11-01 15:17:30 2017-11-01 13:17:30      1 20.08333 mins                  NA
> ```

Comment: while trying this snippet I observed one more thing that sometimes it fetches other Id's spot to the spot_new for another Id (Mostly at the end cases like end of the Id's spot and beginning of another Id's spot new) column in some cases.Is it because of the ungroup and mutate?Could you advise on this

Answer (score 1):

Here we get the row index with `.I` of the next row by adding 1 to it.  To take care of edge cases where the last row of a group have 'start' and 'end' as equal, use the `pmin` to get the last row (not clear about what to do in that case though)

```
 i1 <- data[, .I[pmin(which(start == end)+1, .N)], Id]$V1
 data[i1, spot_new := spot][]
# Id               start                 end                spot type   consumption            spot_new
#1:  1 2017-11-01 08:31:35 2017-11-01 08:37:30 2017-11-01 08:21:30    1 10.08333 mins                <NA>
#2:  1 2017-11-01 09:45:35 2017-11-01 09:45:35 2017-11-01 09:40:35    1  5.00000 mins                <NA>
#3:  1 2017-11-01 10:37:35 2017-11-01 11:27:30 2017-11-01 09:48:35    3 49.00000 mins 2017-11-01 09:48:35
#4:  1 2017-11-01 13:37:35 2017-11-01 15:17:30 2017-11-01 13:17:30    1 20.08333 mins                <NA>
```